# Integration - finding an explicit formula

Tags: integration

The question in my textbook asks:

> If $f$ is a continuous function such that $$\int\limits_0^x{f(t)dt}=xe^{2x}+\int\limits_0^x{e^{-t}f(t)dt}$$ for all $x$, find an explicit formula for $f(x)$.

My working goes as follows:

I decided to analyse the equation as an integration by parts $\left(\int udv=uv-\int vdu\right)$, so

$uv]_0^x=xe^{2x}\\
\therefore \text{a possible substitution is}\\
\quad u=t,\qquad v=e^{2t}\\
\quad du=dt,\quad dv=2e^{2t}dt$

and

$\int\limits_0^xvdu=\int\limits_0^x{e^{-t}f(t)dt}\\
\therefore e^{-t}f(t)=e^{2t}\\
\quad f(t)=e^{3t}$

This looks sound until I try equating $\int\limits_0^xudv=\int\limits_0^x f(t)dt$, whereupon I get $f(t)=2te^{2t}$.

I think I don't quite understand what an explicit formula is.

Comment: Your solution looks alright to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if you differentiate the equation:

$$f(x) = e^{2x} + 2xe^{2x} + e^{-x}*f(x)$$

$$f(x)(1 - e^{-x}) = e^{2x} + 2xe^{2x}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{2x} + 2xe^{2x}}{1 - e^{-x}}$$

Comment: I thought about differentiating, but I wasn't sure whether I should differentiate by x or t. I can see now that $\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt=f(x)-f(0)$

Comment: @ahorn: you can't differentiate with respect to $t$ since the scope of $t$ is restricted to inside the integral. In other words, $t$ is a dummy variable; to see this, we could simply change the $t$ in the integral to $s$ and not change anything outside of the integral. That is, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ahorn : The formula you wrote in your comment is not correct, the correct one is $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt = f(x)$. Think about this. :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Can you please explicate your statement? I thought that $\int\limits_0^x f(t)dt = F(x) - F(0) \text{ where } F'(y)=f(y)$

Comment: @ahorn : Yes, that is true! But what is the derivative of the *constant*  $F(0)$? :) It's definitely not $f(0)$!

Comment: I see. $F(0)$ is always constant. I also just looked at the FTC part 1. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint : All you have to do is differentiate! This is actually pretty much the solution... I let you figure out the rest ; feel free to comment and discuss.

Remark : You do understand what an explicit formula is, you just didn't manage to find it yet. $f(t) = 2t e^{2t}$ is an example of an explicit formula for a function of a real variable.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

Hint: As you have proper condition for the function so you could use [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) for both sides.